# How to style pseudo counter in CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How do I change the font size of the counter in this example:

```
<style>
p
{
counter-increment: myIndex;
}

p:before
{
content:counter(myIndex);
}
</style>
```

Webpage content

```
<p>First make a variable (myIndex) and make it increase every time a p element occurs.</p>
<p>Then insert the counter in front of all p elements</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> For the counter property to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `font-size` for the `:before` psuedo.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7XXB/)

```
p {
    counter-increment: myIndex;
}
p:before {
    content:counter(myIndex);
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: I see the issue.  I had another pseudo that was conflicting with the font size.